# Display the 3 latest WordPress Posts on a Static Page Outside WordPress

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how to get the 3 latest WordPress posts and display each in its own div on a static HTML page, outside of WordPress. The PHP I am using will pull any number of posts, however, they all display in the same div. In the screen capture, I just replicated the PHP 3 times, each in a new div. I would like to display a different post in each div.

PHP I am using

```php
            <?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-load.php');
$args = array(
// 'cat' => 3, // Only source posts from a specific category
'posts_per_page' => 1 // Specify how many posts you'd like to display
);

$latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
$latest_posts->the_post(); ?>
```

[image: static html page displaying wordpress posts]

Comment: You could do this entirely within Javascript by making a request to `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`, and it would be more reliable too

Comment: Interesting idea.

Comment: It would even work if the sites were hosted on different servers, something a PHP based solution could not do without major performance problems. Even a custom RSS widget would be better

Answer (score 1):

Set this to 3:

```
 'posts_per_page' => 3
```

Add your div in loop

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-load.php');
$args = array(
// 'cat' => 3, // Only source posts from a specific category
'posts_per_page' => 3 // Specify how many posts you'd like to display
);

$latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
    $latest_posts->the_post(); 
    ?>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"> 
       <?php echo get_the_title(); ?> 
    </div>
    <?php
    
}
```

?>

Comment: Yea, right, changing 1 to 3 will pull 3 posts, but I want 3 posts in 3 different divs.

Comment: Can you please add your div structure. I will setup loop for you

Comment: Sure.

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
POST 1
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
POST 2
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
POST 3
</div>

Comment: I have updated code. I hope that will helps. Let me know If you have any questions

Comment: Thanks, Jagruti!  Looking at your code, are you sure this won't just repeat the same post 3 times?

Comment: Yes, It will display 3 different post in loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111903/discussion-between-jagruti-rakholiya-and-controlz).